# Highcharts Bar - Display DataLabel at the right end of the plot

Tags: highcharts

I need the dataLabels to be always displayed at the right end of bar chart irrespective of the data value. According to the Highcharts API, the dataLabel position is adjustable only relative of its current position. Is there a way to change the datalabel position relative to the chart area?

Answer (score 4):

You can also position data labels in the `render` event:

```
events: {
  render: function() {
    var chart = this;

    chart.series.forEach(function(s) {
      s.points.forEach(function(p) {
        if (p.dataLabel) {
          p.dataLabel.attr({
            x: chart.plotWidth - p.dataLabel.width
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yt1joqLr/1/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events

Comment: Thanks a lot, really helped me. Do you think there's any performance drawbacks in using this approach compared to pure CSS one?

Comment: Hi @Yair Cohen, I don't think so, data labels are only moved to other position, the chart is not redrawn.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for something like this?

[image: Highcharts bar chart with right-aligned dataLabels]

If you [make the labels HTML elements](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting#html) instead of SVG elements..

```js
plotOptions: {
    bar: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            allowOverlap: true,
            //Labels are easier to move around if we switch from SVG to HTML:
            useHTML: true,
        }
    }
}
```

..it's quite easy to move them around using CSS:

```css
.highcharts-data-labels.highcharts-bar-series {
    /* Stretch the labels container across the whole chart area: */
    right: 0;
}

.highcharts-label.highcharts-data-label,
.highcharts-label.highcharts-data-label span {
    /* Disable the default label placement.. */
    left: auto !important;
    /* ..and put them along the right side of the container */
    right: 8px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ncbedru8/